# Calling ajax as deferred promise and receiving errors

Tags: jquery, deferred, promise

I'm trying to get the following code to work, but I'm obviously missunderstanding how $.Deferred works. Please could somebody help.

The idea is, call GetParameters, process result, call GetStats, process result. Also to set busy to true before and false to after. I'm expecting only one error to propogate down to .fail().

```
    self.refreshParams = $.ajax({
            url: self.ToAddress() + "/GetParameters",
            data: "{}",
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/javascript",
            dataType: "jsonp"
        });

    self.refreshMachines = $.ajax({
            url: self.ToAddress() + "/GetStats",
            data: "{}",
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/javascript",
            dataType: "jsonp"
      });

    self.refresh = function () {
      var d = $.Deferred();

      d.pipe(self.refreshParams)
      .done(function (p) {
          self.params(p);
      });

      d.pipe(self.refreshMachines)
      .done(function (m) {
          self.machines(m);
      });

      d.always(function() {
        self.busy(false);
      })
      .fail(function (x, e) {
          self.errorText(x);
      });

      d.resolve();
    }
```

UPDATE:

I've changed it to:

```
        self.refreshParams = function() {
          return $.ajax({
                url: self.ToAddress() + "/GetParameters",
                data: "{}",
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/javascript",
                dataType: "jsonp"
            });
        };

        self.refreshMachines = function() {
          return $.ajax({
                url: self.ToAddress() + "/GetStats",
                data: "{}",
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/javascript",
                dataType: "jsonp"
          });
        };

        self.refresh = function () {

          $.when(self.refreshParams(), self.refreshMachines())
          .done(function (p, m) {
              self.params(p[0]);
              self.machines(m[0]);
          })
          .done(function() {
            self.busy(false);
          })
          .fail(function (x, e) {
              self.errorText(x);
          });
        }
```

this seems to work if the services are up, but if there is an error, nothing get's down to .fail?

Answer (score 0):

There's no unique way to write code of this type.

You will find it better to work with with separate `.done()` handlers and `.fail()` handlers for the two ajax operations, thus keeping their success and error handling independent of each other.

Then, all you need to do in response to the composite `.when()` watcher is to reset your busy status flag. By doing so in an `.always()` handler, it will be reset regardless of the outcome of the two ajax operations.

I would probably write it something like this:

```
self.refresh = function () {
    self.busy(true);

    var paramsPromise = self.refreshParams().done(self.params).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        self.errorText('refreshParams() : ' + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
    });
    var machinesPromise = self.refreshMachines().done(self.machines).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        self.errorText('refreshMachines() : ' + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
    });

    $.when(paramsPromise, machinesPromise).always(function () {
        self.busy(false);
    });
};
```

Comment: But that totally missuses the chaining/piping of promises. I could do that kind of code using normal callbacks.

Comment: "... totally misuses ..."?!?!? Going back to your opening sentence, I have to agree that you most probably are misunderstanding how $.Deferred works. You asked for advice, you received some and you have been thoroughly dismissive of it. If you don't want help, then don't post questions.

Comment: I can see how my comment might have come off rude, I'm sorry about that. Thanks a lot for the help, I _do_ appreciate it a lot. I'm just frustrated after trying to figure this out all day.

I just meant by missuse that it breaks the whole idea of chaining if you have to define and handle ever call's erros and responses.

Comment: Mladen, OK apology accepted. The point I failed to make clearly in my answer is that compositing the two jqXHRs in a `.when()` clause over-complicates things. Firstly, in the `.done()` callback you would have to branch in order to handle each of the two responses appropriately. Secondly, in the `.fail()` callback you make it extremely difficult to detect which of the two ajax requests failed. There may well be situations where the limitations of this approach are unavoidable, but here I don't think this is the case. Assigning jqXHRs before putting them in the `.when()` is good for readability.